# HTML Form POST vs GET Timeout

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

I have a simple HTML form (text box and submit button) that redirects to the same page, and prints out the input text.

I notice that when using the POST method to send the input text data along, it only works if the page has been loaded for less than ~40 seconds. Any more, and when I press 'Submit', it does not print out the input text. It seems to 'refresh'.

However, when using the GET method (changing all instances of 'post' with 'get' in the code below), this time limit does not seem to exist.

I'm curious as to what causes this difference in behavior. Related posts have directed me to increasing max_execution_time, max_input_time, and default_socket_timeout in php.ini, but none of those seems to have any effect when using the POST method.

Developing environment: Cloud 9 IDE, Chrome web browser.

Here's my code:

```html
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['textentry']))
            echo $_POST['textentry'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Forms</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <form action="index.php" method="post">
         <textarea class="InputTextBox" name="textentry"></textarea>
         <input type="submit" name="TextSubmit" value="Submit"/>
     </form>
 </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you try your code again a few times with post, there should not be a timing issue...

Comment: is this all your code? is this your exact code, not just an example? your issue sounds more like you have some javascript or other code that is causing the issue, not just a timeout in php

Comment: Have you tried this across multiple browsers? or a different server? Seems like a systemspecific error.

Comment: Aaron: I've tried this many times at this point, it's consistently timing out at ~40 seconds.

Sean: This is the exact code that I am running. I'm running it through the Cloud 9 IDE. Would that make any difference?

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

The GET is usually faster because it has no encapsulation (sends data via URL, usually with a 255 character limit) as POST exists encapsulation by being sent by the body of the HTTP request.

Take a look at your code. It is likely that somewhere you are restricting the maximum response time of the requests.

I hope it helps.

Comment: The above is all of the code in my PHP file. The only other place I can imagine the response time of the requests could be restricted would be in the php.ini file provided to me by Cloud9. Do you know of any variables that might be set in it that would cause this behavior?

Comment: In the php.ini look for  max_execution_time and set 0 (no limit).